# Using append in an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, append

I don't get why the following two bits of code give different results:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3,4]

if (x.append(4) == y) or (x == y):
    print(True, x, y)
else:
    print(False, x, y)

#prints True [1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3,4]

if (x == y) or (x.append(4) == y):
    print(True, x, y)
else:
    print(False, x, y)

#prints False [1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Why does swapping the order of the two conditions give different results?** `x.append(4)` makes `x` become `[1,2,3,4]`, as is seen in either output.  So it seems like the condition `x.append(4) == y` should be `True` in either case, satisfying the `or` of the `if` statement.

Comment: I don't understand the down and close votes. This is a legitimate question and has the code needed to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

- While `x.append(4)` does add `4` to `x`, the statement `x.append(4)` actually evaluates to `None`: `append()` *doesn't return anything*, it modifies objects in place.  So if you had `x.append(4) == None` (with `4` or anything!) as a condition in the `or` statement, the `if` would always proceed.
- `x == y` is the statement that is determining the evaluation of the condition (b/c of the first point).  The order matters here because even though the `append()` statement evaluates to `None`, it still modifies `x` within the `if` line.  So in the first case `x==y` is `True` b/c that statement comes after the `append()`, in the second `x==y` is False because it comes before the `append()`.

This examples illustrates how the second can be modified to work like the first:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3,4]

if (x == y) or (x.append(4) == y) or (x == y):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)

#prints True
#the first (x==y) is False but the second is True!
```